# Logging in using django-social-auth in a django unittest

Tags: django, django-testing, django-socialauth, django-unittest

I'm writing a test suite for a django project which needs to login via django-social-auth (its facebook backend) in order to access the website.

The method I'm taking now is:

- for each test:

  - create a test user using facebook API
  - use selenium to login
  - interact with the website once user is logged in

problem is: I need to write a few tests which use the regular django unittest (not selenium). Any idea how I can login using the regular django unittest?

Comment: What do  you mean by login? Do you actually want to test the login process, or can you directly call `auth.login`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django unit test; Login using python-social-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897225/django-unit-test-login-using-python-social-auth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an easy task since the oauth code is very coupled in social-auth. So you really need a oauth service answering.

What I have done is to patch the function `social_auth.utils.urlopen` with a mock that returns previously recorded answers to trick django-social-auth into thinking it is talking with a real oauth provider.

It's a really hacky solution but allows me to test my custom social-auth pipeline in an isolated environment.

Comment: thanks. not optimal but it's django-social-auth's fault that they haven't take testablility seriously.have you thought to fork djano_social_auth and make a "testable djanog-social-auth" ?

Comment: I have a working version of the code I propose, but it's too hackish to be integrated in django-social-auth. I plan to talk with omab to see if I can help to create something in the lines.

Comment: I'm aware of the difficult to test django-social-auth by using unittest because the need to interact with providers by calling their APIs, I've been playing with casperjs to create tests, but those resemble selenium behavior and don't run with django tests of course. I'm open to discuss solutions on this area since testing is really important.

Comment: Social Auth recently integrated a way to easily test things like that.

Please, have a look at http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/master/testing_tools.html