# Django unit test; Login using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-authentication, python-social-auth

I would like to write unit tests for my Django app that is using [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth).
It all works great when running Django and using a browser, thanks python-social-auth!

However, I can't seem to write unit tests because I can't create an authenticated client to test with.

Has anyone done so successfully?
How did you get an authenticated client()?

I have tried this (the login returns false and does not work):

```
self.c = Client()
self.u = User.objects.create(username="testuser", password="password", is_staff=True, is_active=True, is_superuser=True)
self.u.save()
self.auth = UserSocialAuth(user=self.u, provider="Facebook")
self.auth.save()
self.c.login(username=self.u.username, password=self.u.password)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it:

My mistake was thinking that it mattered how that Client got authenticated, for unit testing the views/endpoints oauth really doesn't need to come into play at all.

this worked for me:

```
    self.user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', password='12345', is_active=True, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True) 
    self.user.set_password('hello') 
    self.user.save() 
    self.user = authenticate(username='testuser', password='hello') 
    login = self.c.login(username='testuser', password='hello') 
    self.assertTrue(login)
```

Comment: What if you really want to test that social auth is working? Not the views, but the authentication itself. Imagine that you need to make sure that your social buttons are actually working. How to do this in a fast and easy way?

Comment: @dangonfast wouldn't the fact that you're able to see the views be indication that the auth is working? Assuming of course the views are *@login_required* or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround to the issue by using the [django.test.Client.force_login()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) method instead. With it, you need to fetch a user from the database, whose data is probably stored in a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading), and specify the authentication backend in the second argument.

Here's the code I've used:

```
from random import sample

class SubscribeTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = (
        "auth.User.json", "social_django.UserSocialAuth.json",
        "<myapp>.CustomProfileUser.json", "<myapp>.SubscriptionPlan.json"
    )

    def test_user_logged_in(self):
        users = User.objects.all()
        user = sample(list(users), 1)[0]
        # This isn't actually used inside this method
        social_user = user.social_auth.get(provider="auth0")

        self.client.force_login(
            user, "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend"
        )
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse("<myappnamespace>:subscribe")
        )
        print(response.content)

        # Looking for a way to fetch the user after a
        # response was returned? Seems a little hard, see below
```

I am not sure how you can access a user in a Django unit test scenario after having received a `Response` object, which as the documentation observes *is not* the same as the usual `HttpResponse` used in production environments. I have done [a quick research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9332541/2069269) and it does look like developers aren't intended to do that. In my case I didn't need that so I didn't dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

If one checks [Python Social Auth - Django source code](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/tests/test_views.py), one will see a file in `social-app-django/tests/test_views.py` that contains an example to test authenticating the user with Facebook.

```
from unittest import mock

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.urls import reverse

from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
from social_django.views import get_session_timeout


@override_settings(SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY='1',
                   SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET='2')
class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        session = self.client.session
        session['facebook_state'] = '1'
        session.save()

    def test_begin_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('social:begin', kwargs={'backend': 'facebook'}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        url = reverse('social:begin', kwargs={'backend': 'blabla'})
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

    @mock.patch('social_core.backends.base.BaseAuth.request')
    def test_complete(self, mock_request):
        url = reverse('social:complete', kwargs={'backend': 'facebook'})
        url += '?code=2&state=1'
        mock_request.return_value.json.return_value = {'access_token': '123'}
        with mock.patch('django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase'
                        '.set_expiry', side_effect=[OverflowError, None]):
            response = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
            self.assertEqual(response.url, '/accounts/profile/')
```

To use with another social backend is relatively straightforward; simply substitute `facebook` with the one one is using.

Also, note that the example doesn't consider partial pipelines but the code can be adjusted to consider them too.

---

**Note:**

- Agree that [their docs](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tests.html) could be improved.